# Find how often data passes zero in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm dealing with time series data using python's pandas DataFrame.
Given that this time series has a value in the range of -10 to 10, we want to find out how many times it passes by 3.
In the simplest case, you can check if the values in the previous and current columns are small or large based on 3 to see if there are any changes.
Is there a function in pandas to help with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a sample dataset and expected output, along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find how many times 0 come out

use `pd.count(axis=columns)`

```
    import pandas as pd

    path = ('./test.csv')
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(path,encoding='utf8')

    print(dataframe.count(axis='columns'))
```